# Separate parts to single mesh

Tags: mesh

When I add a model with seperatly parts from an other program it loads into a single mesh instead of separate ones, how do I fix that

Comment: your question is not clear, are you talking about a single mesh or a single object with different meshes within? For the second case, select each mesh with L then press P (Separate) > Selection, or select all and press P > By Loose Parts

Comment: What is the external file format? Could you provide an exemple?

Comment: @lemon it's obj

Comment: Moon like for an example I exported 4 meshes in single time and when I open it in the 2.8 workspace it's only a single mesh, but when I used to open it on the 2.79 it was 4, I want to know how to import them as separate meshes in 2.8

Comment: Is 'split by object' option checked in the import panel (bottom left)?

Comment: I don't know let me check when can open, if it's checked should I uncheck it or nah?